# Using SVG for additive color mixing (additive blending)

Tags: graphics, colors, svg, transparency, svg-filters

Coming from a graphic design background I know how to cheat to create an effect of [additive color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color). The same basic solution is proposed in [another post on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669491/are-there-ways-to-use-additive-color-mixing-in-web-development).

The post above refers to transparent `.png` files but the concept is the same. The basic effect I'd like to create is like the one [pictured here](http://www.d.umn.edu/~mharvey/colorwheel.jpg).

I'd love to do it in SVG so that it can scale and so that when I am talking about a given topic (let's just say the topic is 'green') I can enlarge that portion of the graphic and the overlapping areas would still display correctly.

These posts seem to get pretty close:

- [Algorithm for Additive Color Mixing for RGB Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726549/algorithm-for-additive-color-mixing-for-rgb-values)
- [Question about "Additive blending" and "Hue replacement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750290/question-about-additive-blending-and-hue-replacement)

But none of the above deal with SVG so let me give it a whirl.

Comment: I just logged in and saw the answer below, skimming it it looks like exactly what I was thinking of but...I created a graphic in Adobe Illustrator but realized regular transparency would give me additive color so I simulated with fully opaque colors; I don't think that will help...would a 3 layer (3 overlapping rings) graphic with regular transparency posted to a fiddle work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode, Example 2:

```
circle { mix-blend-mode: screen; }

<svg>
    <circle cx="40" cy="40" r="40" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="80" cy="40" r="40" fill="lime"/>
    <circle cx="60" cy="80" r="40" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 13):

Right now you can do this with [SVG filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html). Since your interest lies in mixing colors, you might be interested in researching the following filter primitives: [feBlend](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feBlendElement), [feComposite](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feCompositeElement), [feColorMatrix](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement) and [feComponentTransfer](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feComponentTransferElement).

If you want to learn the easy way (Inkscape) see [this blogpost](http://fedev.blogspot.se/2008/04/filter-effects-blend.html). I can also recommend reading the [Inkscape book](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/index.html) and in particular how to do [custom filters](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Filters.html). [Here's one page](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Filters-Compositing.html) showing feBlend with similar results as in your basic effect example.

**Update:** [here's the relevant svg file](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/images/FILTERS/Filters_Blend.svg) from the inkscape book, it should look like the image below in browsers that support svg filters (and the `BackgroundImage` filter input, note that Gecko doesn't support `BackgroundImage` and `enable-background`). [image: feBlend variations]

Comment: I had never even heard of those filters as part of the standard! Upon first glance I thought 'fe' might be some sort of vendor prefix, boy was I wrong. Thanks.

Comment: The problem with these examples is that they rely on "enable-background" - which doesn't work on either webkit or mozilla right now (don't know about opera). If you're going to do this using filters, I think you have to pull in images (or create color circles using lighting effects)

Comment: The examples perhaps use `enable-background`, but it's possible to avoid using that. Yes, Opera has had support for `enable-background` for a long time. IIRC IE10 also supports `enable-background`.

Comment: FYI - I've filed a bug against Chromium for enable-background support. If you have an example without enable-background, I'd love to see it. I haven't been able to figure this out myself

Comment: It's possible to use <feImage> that references some particular elements in the svg as a partial workaround (however, note that Firefox doesn't support that). This way you can composite/blend two or more arbitrary elements.

Answer (score 5):

This version replaces an earlier version that wasn't truly cross-browser. I realized that I didn't need separate shapes for the various circles, I could clone, reposition and recolor the original shape within the filter.

```html
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="600px" height="600px" viewbox="0 0 600 600">
    
    <defs>
    <filter id="B4" x="-150%" width="400%" y="-150%" height="400%">
      <feOffset in="SourceGraphic" result="pre-red" dx="-70" dy="-120"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="pre-red" type="matrix" result="red" values="0 0 0 0 1
                                                       0 0 0 0 0 
                                                       0 0 0 0 0 
                                                       0 0 0 1 0"/>

      <feOffset in="SourceGraphic" result="pre-blue" dx="70" dy="-120"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="pre-blue" type="matrix" result="blue" values="0 0 0 0 0
                                                       0 0 0 0 0 
                                                       0 0 0 0 1 
                                                       0 0 0 1 0"/> 
      <feBlend mode="screen" in="red" in2="blue" result="main"/>
      <feBlend mode="screen" in="main" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
    </defs>
    
       <circle filter="url(#B4)" cx="200" cy="250" r="100"  fill="#00FF00"  />
    
    </svg>
```

Comment: Not working on Mozilla and Webkit is definitely a deal breaker. Could you point me in the direction of more info (or explain a bit more) relating to "in filter" effects (the first example)? Looking at it, I feel like I basically get it but I don't see anything that would create the yellow or the cyan (I assume 'final' is white) nor do I see a black stroke (is that because there is no width assigned to the stroke?). Thanks.

Comment: I saw the 'enable-background' references and the notes, I'll go back and read them more carefully though, thanks.