# SVG―additive blendmode

Tags: colors, svg, svg-filters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using SVG for additive color mixing (additive blending)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943905/using-svg-for-additive-color-mixing-additive-blending)

I am looking out to find a way to create an interactive illustration of additive colors as shown in this image:

[image: color wheel]

The red, blue and green areas should be »draggable« but since I am not that familiar with such kind of color processing I the only idea that came into my mind was the use of a blend-mode filter for each of the elements. The [`<feBlend>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feBlendElement) filter does not support »additive«, but there are also the [`<feColorMatrix>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement) and [`<feConvolveMatrix>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feConvolveMatrixElement) filters which seem to offer a wide range of possible color transformations.

Is it possible to create an additive blend-mode with these filters? I would appreciate links to any additional kind of resource/tutorial where I could get more Information about how these filters work!

Greetings...

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943905/svg-to-render-additive-color-transparency

Comment: thanks for this, seems to answer my question... Perhaps I should have added this to my question: Are there solutions that work in all major browsers (ff, opera, safari, chrome)?

Comment: philipp - the second answer to that question has my solution - which is cross-browser